# How to connect 6 pin connector to Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, cable, connectors

I want to know how to integrate 6 pin connector to Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. Since the ends are male, So I'll be using female-to-female connector to connect with GPIO.

**6 Pin Connector:**
[image]

Comment: What is this component ?

Comment: Can you give link of product ? I searched a little bit but didn't see any datasheet

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering over some internet researches.

Your product is replica of [this](http://www.waveshare.com/uart-fingerprint-reader.htm) product (*I guess*). You need to use jumper cables to connect it and wire connection is

- Red = VCC
- Black = GND
- Yellow = TXD
- White = RXD
- Blue = BL (*backlight*)
- Green = RST

Probably your product will **beep** after successfully connection too like [referenced](http://www.waveshare.com/uart-fingerprint-reader.htm) product.

Try other product's datasheets for further references

Answer (score 1):

According to my product with 6 pins too, I have following configuration, connecting it to an UART USB adapter. Seems that only 4 pins are needed, TD/RD/GND/Vin(5V)

- Vin is not working in 3V on my part so 5v is needed

[image]

An image is available [image]

Comming from [this store](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shipping-USB-Fingerprint-Sensor-Support-Android-Windows-System-Optical-Fingerprint-Reader-Sensor/32475559052.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.z82aTt)